# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'M.layout.force')

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsnetworkx

I'm new to JSNetworkX. I created a graph using the examples from jsnetworkx.org but I can only log it, I can't display it.

So this is `index.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
  <script src="jsnetworkx.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src = "script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this the code written in `script.js`:

```
var G = jsnx.completeGraph(6);
console.log(G.nodes());
jsnx.draw(G, {
    element: 'body',
    weighted: true,
    edgeStyle: {
        'stroke-width': 10
    }
});
```

This is the output: *[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*

And this is the error i get:

> JSNetworkX error - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'M.layout.force')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was including the latest version of D3.js.

Changing

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>`

will fix it.